# Need help removing Android ListView items using CheckBoxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a list of tasks that I am displaying inside of a ListView. Inside of each ListView item is a CheckBox with the task title and a TextView displaying the due date. What I am trying having trouble with is removing the item from the list when the Checkbox inside the ListView item is checked.

What I have at the moment is an OnCheckChangedListener that is set for the CheckBox, inside of the Adapter for the listview. This is set in the getView() method. When the Checkbox is clicked the task is removed from the ArrayList, and a new CustomAdapter is made and applied to the listview using the new taskList. This did not work so I added a Handler to make these changes on the UI thread. Still doesn't work. From the logs I can tell that the listener is getting called but the items are not removed.

```
ArrayList<Task> taskList;
Context mContext;
ListView listView;
Handler handler;

public CustomAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Task> taskList){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.taskList = taskList;
    this.handler = new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return taskList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return taskList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listview_item,parent,false);
    }

    final View row = convertView;

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTask);
    TextView textTaskDueDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTaskDueDate);

    checkBox.setText(taskList.get(position).getTask());
    textTaskDueDate.setText("Due Date: " + taskList.get(position).getDueDate());

    checkBox.setTag(position);

    listView = parent.findViewById(R.id.listViewTasks);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                Log.i("CheckBox Listener", "Check heard");
                Log.i("Button Tag", String.valueOf(buttonView.getTag()));
                Log.i("taskList length before", String.valueOf(taskList.size()));
                taskList.remove(buttonView.getTag());
                Log.i("taskList length after", String.valueOf(taskList.size()));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: why are you calling it inside the handler? did you debug and check that the remove method is actually removing the item you are trying to remove?

Comment: Right, the taskList.remove(buttonView.getTag()) call doesn't have to be there, but since setting a new Adapter makes changes to the UI thread setAdapter() should be called there? I'm new to Android.

Comment: you can just remove the item from the list using remove() and call notifyDatasetChanged to notify adapter of the changes. no need to set adapter to list again.

Comment: I just tried it with and without the handler, no luck.

Comment: update your code in question with what you tried.

Comment: did you debug and check that `taskList.remove(buttonView.getTag());` is actually removing item from taskList?

Comment: Ok that seems to be part of the problem. The size of the list is unchanged before and after remove(). I'm getting the expected indices from getTag(), but remove doesn't seem to be working. Why might this be? I added the updated code.

Comment: because `getTag()` is returning object and not an int which remove expects, try converting it into int and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never would have thought the issue was there. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that to remove item at given position using `remove()` it expects paramter to be of type `int`. Currently using

```
taskList.remove(buttonView.getTag()); 
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Method `getTag()` is returning `Object` and not an `int` thus remove will not remove item at position. You will need to convert object returned by `getTag()` to int and thus it will remove item at given position.